# Android no menu items showing in Action Bar

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I am developing an Android app and I am trying to put a menu item into the ActionBar. 
It has enough space, so it shouldn't be on the overflow or anything. 
In my menu.xml I have added that item + `android:showAsAction="ifRoom|withText"`

However, no matter how large the screen is, that damn menu will not show up on the ActionBar (although it is present in the menu, if the user presses a key).
Unfortunately I cannot post any full-code since I am under a non-disclosure agreement, but I will answer all questions.

The section where I inflate the menu:

```
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.drinks, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case android.R.id.home:

            NavUtils.navigateUpFromSameTask(this);
            return true;

        case R.id.done:
            //stuff


        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
```

Comment: what text is on that action bar? is it is a long string and a big icon, it might get into the overflow. On higher APIs, the overflow is not shown as long as the user has a menu-button.

Comment: There is no icon and just a short String : "Done"

Comment: What is the targetSDK you've set and on what device does this issue appear?

Comment: targetSDK is 17. On all the devices I tried, including a HTC explorer, a BlueStacks emulator and a Samsung Galaxy III

Comment: HpTerm, what do you mean by  " don't @Override the onCreateOptionsMenu" , I am doing exactly that.

Comment: parent class is `Activity` or `ActionBarActivity`? Above code is correct, I am sure you're missing something minor

Comment: parent class is Activity

Comment: The action bar appears on post ICS devices? Or it doesn't appear on pre-ICS?

Comment: It appears on all devices (both pre and post ics)

Comment: That annotation is irrelevant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you have only a menu item, use this attribute instead: `android:showAsAction="always"`.

**EDIT** Above works all the time if you're running the code on post Honeycomb. But, in order to run on pre-Honeycomb, according to [developer article](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html), you need to extend from `ActionBarActivity`, that means adding compatibility support v4 & v7 and set the following theme for your activity:

`<activity android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light" ... >`

... or a Them.AppCompat theme. Or use one of your own that extends from these.

Comment: The action bar appears on post ICS devices? Or it doesn't appear on pre-ICS?

Comment: I believe this might be the right answer, since I have tested my code now on a S Galaxy 4 and it works, but not on HTC Explorer with API 10.

Let me try and test your advice.

Comment: On some devices the overflow menu may not appear (the 3 dots on the right side of the action bar), in such cases there is a menu button provided on the bottom left side of the phone.